# Hide the "Post Published. View Post" admin notice in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Does anyone know how to hide the Post Published message that appears once a post has been published on a WordPress site in the admin.

I have seen this example to hide the Update Available message to all but the admin, but I am not sure what needs to be added to remove the save message:

```
function hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users() 
{
    if (!current_user_can('update_core')) {
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_update_notice_to_all_but_admin_users', 1 );
```

I need to remove the message on both regular posts and on custom post types.  As far as I can tell, it should be just a case of replacing `'update_nag'` but I am unsure of what to replace it with.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should remove the "Post Published" message.

```
add_filter( 'post_updated_messages', 'post_published' );

function post_published( $messages )
{
    unset($messages[post][6]);
    return $messages;
}
```

The above is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16017461/3204827) answer, modified to only remove the "Post Published" message.

Comment: It is recommended to quote string in array key
unset($messages['post'][6]);
Implicit conversion may fail sometimes.